# How to pass Unreal Engine 4 Niagara Int Array to Blueprint

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am struggling to retrieve a Niagara Int Array from a Blueprint. While researching this topic, I came across the "Niagara Get Int32 Array" Node, but it is not working as expected. For some reason, I only get a valid Array returned when I try and retrieve a User exposed Parameter, but when I try and get a System or Emitter Array, it does not return a valid array.

[This returns Length 0 (4 is expected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKyN2.png)

[This returns Length 4 ( as expected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DHYA.png)

My Question is it possible to retrieve System or Emitter Arrays from Niagara Systems and pass them to a blueprint? Am I using this Node correctly? Or should I be doing this with a 2D grid and a Texture which is interpreted in a shader later?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export Particle Data interface is super limited and also does not deliver persistent particle indices over multiple frames. Additionally, it only allows to output two vectors and a scalar parameter, not an array or list of values.

It turns out that it is not possible to retrieve an array from a Niagara GPU emitter. The solution was to use *Grid Collections* instead of arrays and output those as Render Target Textures that would encode the desired information. These textures can then be interpreted by a custom compute shader or via a blueprint ( this is only advisable if you are going to code your own *ReadRenderTargetPixel* function, since the native one blocks the render thread)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these two data interfaces:

- The Export data interface can send an array of particle data to a blueprint (there is an example system using this in the Niagara_Advanced map of the content examples)
- The Array data interface can be used to send an array from blueprint to Niagara or between emitters.